# Geo Filter with Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to dataframes with spark and it's sometimes weird.
Let's say I have a dataframe containing Logs with Latitude and Longitude coordinates.

```
 LogsDataFrame.printSchema :
 root
 |-- lat: double (nullable = false)
 |-- lon: double (nullable = false)
 |-- imp: string (nullable = false)
 |-- log_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pubuid: string (nullable = true)
```

On the other hand I have a simple method

```
within(lat : Double, long : Double, radius : Double) : Boolean
```

that tells if lat and lon are in a certain radius of a pre-defined location.

Now, how do I filter point Log that do not satisfy within. I tried

`logsDataFrame.filter(within(logsDF("lat"), logsDF("lon"), RADIUS)`

But it does not infer the Double and instead it gives back Column as type. 
How can I get this working? 
The docs in the spark site are a bit simplistic, I'm sure I'm missing something.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking you need at least two things to make it work. First you have to create an `UDF` wrapping `within`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, lit}

val withinUDF = udf(within _)
```

Next, when the UDF is called, radius should be marked as a literal:

```
df.where(withinUDF($"lat", $"long", lit(RADIUS)))
```

Since not every type can be passed this way and creating wrappers and calling `lit` is rather tedious you may prefer currying:

```
def within(radius: Double) = udf((lat: Double, long: Double) => ???)

df.where(within(RADIUS)($"lat", $"long"))
```

Comment: This is awesome, works great. I was missing the literal part. I'll definitely rewrite the code with currying. Just started writing Scala. Thank you.